# Finding the distance from the origin

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors

The  position vector  at  time  $t$  of  another  point, $Q$,  is given by 
$OQ = (t^2, 1-t, 1-t^2)$, $t \ge  0$. Find the value of  $t$  for  which the distance  from  $Q$  to the  origin  is minimum.

This is where I have reached

$d(t) = \sqrt{(2t^4-t^2-2t+2)}$. How do I continue from here to get the value of t?

Ok based on your suggestions I solved for the first derivative and got this

$d'(t)= 4t^3-t-1/\sqrt{(2t⁴-t²-2t+2)}$. I guess I need to solve this equation $4t^3-t-1=0$. It's eluding me

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the distance of a point $(x, y, z)$ to the origin? If so, do the same thing substituting $x=t^2, y=1-t, z=t-t^2$.

Comment: You can always minimise the square of the distance ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $d(t)$ be the distance between $Q$ and the origin. Then
$$d(t)=\sqrt{(t^2-0)^2+(1-t-0)^2+(1-t^2-0)^2}$$
To find the minimum distance between the origin and $Q$, we want to minimize $d(t)$. This can be done by solving $$\left.\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} d(t)\right|_{t=t_0}=0$$for $t_0$, which will be the time at which the distance is the minimum. Of course, you can use the second derivative to verify that this critical point is indeed a **minimum**.

Note, that minimizing $d(t)$ can be done by minimizing $d^2(t)$ since $d(t)\geq 0$.

Comment: I solved for the first derivative and got d'(t)= 4t³-t-1/√(2t⁴-t²-2t+2). Looks like solving for t is eluding me

Comment: This looks correct. So now you set that equation equal to zero and solve for $t$. As I remark in my answer, it may be easier to find the first derivative of $$d^2(t)=2t^4-t^2-2t+2$$ since this eliminates the pesky square root.

Comment: Yea my difficulty now is in solving the 4t³-t-1 for the value of t

Comment: Yes, I plugged this into Wolfram Alpha and the roots are rather nasty. Are you sure that you have the correct expression for $OQ$ in terms of $t$? Also, where'd you get this question?

Comment: Yea from the IB questionbank, 3rd edition, higher level.

Comment: the value of t is actually 0.761

Comment: Yes an approximation can be made, however the exact values are rather nasty (one could use the cubic formula). See Raffaele's answer for an approximation method.

Comment: Yea his answer is correct, but am struggling to understand the value theorem method. I need to go and revise that. Besides is there no other clearer method than that?

Comment: Well you can google root approximation methods and there'll be a lot. The one Raffaele uses is Newton's method. Here's a link: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method

Comment: Great. Thank so much. At least this is a good guide

Comment: I got the value of t after the 7th iteration. I think the Newton method is more clearer than the rest..it looks long, but better.lol

Answer (score 0):

$f(t)=4 t^3-t-1$

As $f(0.5)=-1$ and $f(1)=+2$ for the intermediate value theorem there exists a root in $(0.5,1)$

Now apply Newton's method to find an approximate solution

Let's start with $t_0=0.5$ and define for $n>0$

$t_{n+1}=t_n-\dfrac{f(t_n)}{f'(t_n)}$

as $f'(t)=12t^2-1$ we have

$t_{n+1}=t_n-\dfrac{4 t_n^3-t_n-1}{12t_n^2-1}$

after a few iterations we find the root

$t\approx 0.76069$

which is the requested minimum where

$d\approx 0.754745$

Hope this helps

Comment: Interesting...is there any other way apart from the value theorem method?

Comment: Thanks man. It has been very helpful

Comment: I got the value of t after the 7th iteration. Was long but worth it. Thanks man